# Is it possible to search text over a project in all commits?

Tags: cvs

I have a message error on production that has no match with any of my source code files. I thought this could be related to an old version. Since I don't know which version it could be I thought if it's possible to use some file/content search over all versions of all files to see if this was implemented, it's removal was commited and now there's no evidence of it. Is this possible over CVS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All revisions of one cvs file are stored in a single physical file in the repository.  If the files you check in to cvs are text files, that single physical file is a text file with simple embedded meta-data markers.  The single physical file has a ,v suffix.

The repository is the directory referred to in your ./CVS/Root file.

So try to find the repository directory tree, check its parents and children to see the full repository, look at a few ,v files, and try text search(es) on some or all the ,v files.

(NOTE: this answer based on my use of cvs on several Linux variants, may not be generally applicable)